# Recycler View change view after select and EditText

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm making an Android app in Xamarin that depending on some data, enables the edit texts in the View.
[image: Entrie layout]

```
switch (types)//data taken from a class
{
case 0://Disable EditText (by default it's disable)
vh.Tipo.SetImageResource(Resource.Mipmap.server);
vh.SubTitle.Visibility=ViewStates.Invisible;
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(vh.IdInventario.Text))
vh.borrame.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
break;
case -1://Enable EditText
vh.Tipo.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
vh.SubTitle.Text = "Dep";
vh.borrame.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
vh.IdInventario.Enabled=true;
break;

}
```

[image: This is how it normally see]

The problem begins when I select the enable EditText to write some text and when shows off the keyboard some of the views resets themselves, this pases inclusive just when it shows the keyboard and hiding it.

[image]

I tried making keypress listener where i used `NotiffyDataSetChanged` and `NotifyItemChanged` (not at the same time) aftetr save the text I wrote to see if it solves the problem but apparently does nothing, I want to know what's hapennig and a posible solution of this.